# Global caption issue with table when using subcaption package

Tags: tables, subcaption

Firstly I apologize if this had been answered before. I have tried looking for it anywhere but I couldn't find any solution.

Anyway, I have a trouble with the caption of my table when I included the subcaption package.

This is the excerpt of the code:

```
    \documentclass{ifacconf}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[hb]
        \centering
        \caption{Test eheh blah}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
            \hline
            Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
            First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
            Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
         \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

And the output is

[withSubcaption http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/513/0o0l.jpg](http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/513/0o0l.jpg)

However, if I removed the subcaption package, the output is as expected

[withoutSubcaption http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/513/75c3.jpg](http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/513/75c3.jpg)

So, I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Cheers.

EDITED:

Following Harish Kumar answer, although it does solve the caption issue in my table, it causes problem in the captions of my other subfigure. Here is the code of the subfigure.

```
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \begin{figure}[htb!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.38\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1.eps}
            \caption{test caption}
            \label{fig:pic1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}{0.38\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic2.eps}
            \caption{test caption}
            \label{fig:pic2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Long caption Long caption.}
        \label{fig:pictures}
    \end{figure}
```

And the output

[subfigure http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/534/7ufa.jpg](http://imageshack.com/scaled/800x600/534/7ufa.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Where we can find `ifacconf.cls`?

Comment: [IFAC Latex template](http://www.ifac-control.org/events/information-for-ifac-authors/ifacconf-latex.zip/view). That's interesting, if I use `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}` instead, the output is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `ifacconf` class is not compatible with `caption`, as the warning

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

tells you. This means that also `subcaption` cannot be used.

In these cases, the good old `subfig` package usually comes to the rescue, but there's a catch: the class defines `\captionwidth` as a command, whereas `subfig` defines it as a dimension register. Moreover, the class wrongly does

```
\let\endfigure\end@float
\let\endtable\end@float
```

This makes the class incompatible with `subfig` too.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\endfigure{\end@float}
\def\endtable{\end@float}
\makeatother

\let\ifacconfcaptionwidth\captionwidth
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\let\captionwidth\ifacconfcaptionwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\caption{Test eheh blah}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
\hline
Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\caption{Test eheh blah}

\subfloat[A subcaption]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
  \hline
  Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
  First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\subfloat[B subcaption]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
  \hline
  Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
  First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

So long as you don't use `subfig` options to change the appearance of the subcaptions, this should be sufficient.

A perhaps better workaround might be

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\endfigure{\end@float}
\def\endtable{\end@float}
\makeatother

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setlength{\captionwidth}{0.8\linewidth}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength{\captionwidth}{0.8\linewidth}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{width=.7\captionwidth}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\caption{Test eheh blah}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
\hline
Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\caption{Test eheh blah}

\subfloat[A subcaption]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
  \hline
  Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
  First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\subfloat[B subcaption]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Margin settings} \\
  \hline
  Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\ \hline
  First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

but my advice is “don't use subfloats with this class”.

[image]