# Overfull table caption when including subcaption package (IFAC paper)

Tags: tables, captions, boxes, subcaption

I am trying to use the subcaption package in the [IFAC paper](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/view).

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
\usepackage{subcaption}
%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Style for IFAC Conferences \& Symposia: Use Title Case for
  Paper Title\thanksref{footnoteinfo}} 
% Title, preferably not more than 10 words.

\author[First]{First A. Author} 

\address[First]{National Institute of Standards and Technology, 
   Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}

\begin{abstract}                % Abstract of not more than 250 words.
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for IFAC
technical meetings.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Five to ten keywords, preferably chosen from the IFAC keyword list.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
%===============================================================================
\section{Figures}

\subsection{Tables}
Tables must be centered and have a caption above them, numbered with
Arabic numerals. See table~\ref{tb:margins} for an example.

\begin{table}[hb]
\begin{center}
\caption{Margin settings}\label{tb:margins}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\\hline
First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\
Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\bibliography{ifacconf}             % bib file to produce the bibliography
```

I need the subcaption package because I want to add subfigures in double columns. However, when I add this package, my table caption becomes overfull. How can I correct this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global caption issue with table when using subcaption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137201/global-caption-issue-with-table-when-using-subcaption-package)